# Separate of nouns and groups of noun tag using nltk from json file

Tags: nltk, part-of-speech

I want to find or separate noun and groups of nouns using NLTK from JSON file, this is the JSON file content:

```
[
  {
    "id": 18009,
    "ingredients": [
      "baking powder",
      "eggs",
      "all-purpose flour",
      "raisins",
      "milk",
      "white sugar"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 28583,
    "ingredients": [
      "sugar",
      "egg yolks",
      "corn starch",
      "cream of tartar",
      "bananas",
      "vanilla wafers",
      "milk",
      "vanilla extract",
      "toasted pecans",
      "egg whites",
      "light rum"
    ]
  },
```

I want to find the `NN`, `NNS`, `NNP`, `NNPS`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import nltk
from nltk import word_tokenize
for a in data:
    for b in a["ingredients"]:
        text = word_tokenize(b)
        res = nltk.pos_tag(text)
        res = [t for t in res if t[1] in ["NN", "NNS", "NNP", "NNPS"]]
        print(res)

#output:
#[('powder', 'NN')]
#[('eggs', 'NNS')]
#[('flour', 'NN')]
#[('raisins', 'NNS')]
#[('milk', 'NN')]
#[('sugar', 'NN')]
#[('sugar', 'NN')]
#[('egg', 'NN'), ('yolks', 'NNS')]
#[('corn', 'NN'), ('starch', 'NN')]
# ...
```

Comment: I am glad that I could help. (please don't forget to upvote and accept the answer :)  )

Comment: I found an error when i run the code on json file
error Keyerror ingredian

Comment: Make sure your json file has the right keys.  ( "ingredian" shouldn't be a key , instead  "ingredients" should be)

Comment: You should open a new question on this website about checking JSON files

Comment: can you tell me how i can separate the remaining part of speech?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, perhaps you are asking about this: s = [('powder', 'NN')]   print(s[0][1])  #'NN'    But comments are not the right place for writing code. You should open new questions if you have new questions